# Apply a filtering mask to a data matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, filtering

I have two matrices:

```
data = imported_data.data; % matrix from hdf5, 30x20000 single
filter = imported_data.invalid_flags == 0; % 30x20000 logical
```

I want to merge information from the two matrices, so that I get a new data matrix with the same dimensions, and with positions where `filter` is `0` set to to `0` or `NaN`. Here's a small example to clarify my question:

```
data =       [3, 4, 5;
              2, 3, 4];
filter =     [0, 1, 1;
              1, 0, 1];
valid_data = [0, 4, 5; % 'reset' values specified in filter
              2, 0, 4];
```

I tried `valid_data = data(filter);`, but that resulted in a 400000x1 single matrix. However, I want to have a matrix `valid_data` with the original dimensions.

Is it necessary to loop over all values or is there a quicker solution?

Comment: the dimensions of `data` and `filter` are the same, so I don't get your point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiplying the arrays element-wise will work:

```
valid_data = data .* filter;
```

Alternatively, to replace with `NaN` we can use a trick with `0/0` division:

```
valid_data = data .* (filter./filter);
```

Finally, you could use logical indexing:

```
valid_data = data; valid_data(~filter) = NaN;
```

Comment: great answer, thanks!

Is there a 'best' way to do it? E.g. considering performance, resources, ...

Comment: I suppose the first suggestion is the "best" as it requires the least operations, but really, you can use any of the above solutions as they're all very lightweight. I am certain that you will have other regions in your code that will require much more resources. To find those regions, use the [_profiler_ tool](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html).